# C# - How to filter list using enum

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

**I have 2 a classes:**

```
public enum ArticleType
{
  News = 1;
  SpecialOffer = 2;
  Service = 3;
}

public ArticleApiDto
{
  public int Id;
  public ArticleType Type;
}
```

Now i have method for getting data from db, something like:

```
public List<ArticleApiDto> GetAll(List<ArticleType> types)
{
  var res = new List<ArticleApiDto>();
  res = context.articles.ToList();
  //do stuff
}
```

Now I would like to filter out Articles from **res** whose **type** is specified in **types** from parameter of method.

**Problem 1:** I actually cant use Contains because ArticleType is enum

**Problem 2:** `List<ArticleType>` is because sometimes i want to pass only one type but sometimes two or three. At the moment i cant figure out better better solution.

Can someone help me with this please I was searching for whole noone but cant figure out

Comment: Try .Where(item => types.Contains(item.Type))  or if that doesnt work in linq2sql, you could convert the types list to an int list and check that the int list contains the article type (which im guessing is an int in the db).

Comment: "I actually cant use Contains because ArticleType is enum". Have you tried? What error are you getting? Cause you should be able to do that.

Comment: Don't forget ToList
`.Where(item => types.Contains(item.Type)).ToList()`

Comment: You should be able to use Enum.Equals for comparison. Like this:
```.Where(item => types.Any(t => item.Type.Equals(t)).ToList()```

Comment: Thank you guys. I have tested all of your suggestions and every single one is working. Thank you again and have a great day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to pass more than one type you can do it like:

Make your enum to be Flags (note that values now can't be 1,2,3,4 and should be 1,2,4,8,16,...:

```
[Flags]
public enum ArticleType
{
  News = 1;
  SpecialOffer = 2;
  Service = 4;
}
```

Now you add up what you want to filter with `|`:

```
filter = ArtickeType.News | ArticleType.Service;
var result = res.Where(x => filter & x.Type != 0).ToList();
```

or:

```
filter = ArtickeType.News | ArticleType.Service | ArticleType.SpecialOffer;
var result = res.Where(x => filter.HasFlag(x.Type)).ToList();
```

To do it with your current enum:

```
public enum ArticleType
{
  News = 1;
  SpecialOffer = 2;
  Service = 3;
}

var filter = new List<ArticleType> { ArticleType.Service, ArticleType.News};
var result = res.Where(x => filter.Contains(x.Type)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This code work with me, I use Linq with contains it may solve your problem.

```html
public static List<ArticleApiDto> GetAll(List<ArticleType> types)
        {
            var res = new List<ArticleApiDto>();
            List<ArticleApiDto> articles = new List<ArticleApiDto>
            {
                new ArticleApiDto{Id = 1, Type = ArticleType.News },
                new ArticleApiDto{Id = 2, Type = ArticleType.SpecialOffer },
            };
           
            var newArticales = articles.Where(i =>
            {
                return types.Contains(i.Type);
            }).ToList();
            return newArticales;
        }
```